# searchbar within tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am trying to set search bar for table, so can anyone tell me that, is it possible to have uisearchabr when table scroll up / pull up and for other case search bar doesn't get appear on screen. Is it possible? If yes, then how?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Took a look at the docs? There's a `tableHeaderView` property.

Comment: but i want to make search bar visible when table scrolls up, not when it scrolls down...

Comment: Then you create uiviewcontroller class and in that you can add the subview of UISearchbar & UITableView.

Comment: Do you want to set it as `tableFooterView`? What do you mean by scroll up? How do you want it to appear on screen?

Comment: @ACB - no, I dnt want to set it as tableFooterView. I want to set it on the top of the screen.

Comment: In that case you can implement scrollViewDelegate `scrollViewDidScroll` and check the `contentOffset `to hide/show search bar.

Comment: You did down vote for me?

Comment: k then ..take a viewController and in this view controller make tableView and when you scroll down then add your search bar

Comment: you did down vote for my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement scrollViewDelegate `scrollViewDidScroll` and check the `contentOffset` to show/hide search bar. Since table view is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, you can depend on this delegate method to decide when to show/hide it.

Basically when the `contentOffset` represents the scrolled up position, you can show this search bar and when the `contentOffset` value starts changing, you can hide the search bar. Use hidden property of the search bar to show/hide it. You can also use `removeFromSuperView`/`addSubview` methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code or concept.Concept is in scroll view delegate function you will check the content offset and display the set the search bar object in table view header.

Code :

```
//MARK: -UIScrollViewDelegate
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y <= - 65.0f) {
        [self.tableView setTableHeaderView:self.searchBar];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Make delegate of `UIScrollViewDelegate` and implement its delegate method,
in this when you start scroll the table then unhide your searchBar and change frame of tableView.

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [mySearchBar setHidden:NO];
    [quotesTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 416)];
}
```